# Using .env in electron builds

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm making an electron app with firebase.
I used an environment variable to hide the API key, but it is not recognized when building.

It was confirmed that it works normally when building after creating an APIkey as a string without using environment variables.

Is there a build option to include the .env file?

**index.js**

```js
import { config } from "dotenv";

config();

const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
};
```

**package.json**

```json
"build": {
    "productName": "NB",
    "appId": "com.nb.electron",
    "asar": true,
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "default"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.icns"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "title": "NB",
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.icns"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ],
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": false,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "perMachine": true,
      "language": 1042,
      "installerIcon": "build/icons/icon.ico",
      "shortcutName": "NB",
      "artifactName": "NB-${version}.${ext}",
      "uninstallDisplayName": "NB"
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "./build/",
      "output": "./dist/"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding this field in your build script you will be able to put your .env in the root folder of your build.
But it will be exposed to users that will install your build.
This method is not perfect but it works fine.

```json
"extraFiles": [
  {
    "from": ".env",
    "to": "."
  }
]
```